# Webmachine: How can I retrieve multiple values from URL via wrq:get_qs_value?

Tags: httpresponse, erlangweb, webmachine

I get this:

```
T = wrq:get_qs_value("name",ReqData)
```

But suppose I want to retrieve "fname", "lname", "gnder", "age", etc. from a form submission. Do I need to repeat variations on the line above for every variable? Or is there a more elegant sytax?

Many thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a good night of sleep, I came up with this answer to my own question:

```
...
L = ["fname", "lname", "gender", "age"],
[ wrq:get_qs_value(X) || X < L ]
...
```

LRP